# Whyt is the space complexity of Dijkstra with heap O(V) instead of (V + E)?

Tags: python, dijkstra, space-complexity

About Dijkstra with min heap(priority queue),,,

```py
import heapq

graph = [
  [(1, 5), (2, 3)],
  [(3, 3), (2, 2)],
  [(4, 4), (5, 2), (3, 7)],
  [(4, 1)],
  [],
  [(4, 5)]
]
v = len(graph)
dist = [math.inf] * v

def dijkstra(start):
  # Init dist / heap / heap with start
  dist[start] = 0
  hq = [(0, start)]

  while hq:
    # pop current shortest distance node
    d, cur = heapq.heappop(hq) 
    if d > dist[cur]: continue # pass decided node
      
    for next, weight in graph[cur]:
      new_dist = dist[cur] + weight
      if new_dist < dist[next]:
        dist[next] = new_dist
        heapq.heappush(hq, (new_dist, next))

  for i in range(v): print(dist[i], end=" ") # print distance
```

I understand O(V) is needed for storing distance.
But doesn't heap need O(E) because it contains a total of E?

So I think space complexity is O(V+E).
Is there anything wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What is your source for claiming it should be O(V)? The space needed for storing the graph information (the statement `graph = [.....]`), even without executing any algorithm on it, already needs O(V+E)...

Comment: @trincot: Input size is not counted towards an algorithm's space complexity.

Comment: OK, that would be called *auxiliary* space complexity.

Answer (score 1):

O(V) is the space complexity for a Dijkstra implementation that uses a heap with a decrease-key operation, and uses decrease-key to update existing heap entries instead of adding multiple entries for the same node. With such an implementation, the heap will have at most one entry per vertex, not one entry per edge.

Comment: If it is impossible updating the existing information? What is the space complexity when just add new one??

Comment: @user19246061, then it is like you have stated it in your question.